# STL container with a specific type as a generic argument

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

Is there any way that I can make a function which takes a container with a specific type (lets say `std::string`) as a parameter

```
void foo(const std::container<std::string> &cont)
{
   for(std::string val: cont) {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
   }
}
```

and call it for every type of stl container as input? like above?

```
std::set<std::string> strset;
std::vector<std::string> strvec;
std::list<std::string> strlist;

foo(strset);
foo(strvec);
foo(strlist);
```

Comment: Yep, it's called a template function. ;)

Comment: It is often considered better to pass a pair of iterators (representing beginning and one-past-the-end of the container, respectively).   As long as iterators meet requirements of the function, it (often, there are some exceptions) doesn't matter what type of containers they were obtained from.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can make `foo` a function template taking a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) for the container type.

e.g.

```
template<template<typename...> typename C>
void foo(const C<std::string> &cont)
{
   for(std::string val: cont) {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
   }
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VSIzX5gi2Hb2ZNAW)

Comment: I think we can generalize it even further. See my answer.

Comment: Lars' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60297543/10147399) is better because it also works with C-style arrays.

Comment: @theWiseBro Yes it's a good idea in general. But I think OP just wants to use it with specific type as `std::string`, so..

Comment: @songyuanyao OP gave std::string as an example. Let's say if he wishes to change this to say `std::vector<char>` someday, he'll have to alter this method as well. I think a more generalized code would have been better.

Comment: @theWiseBro following that path using `void*` as type for parameter should be the way to go.

Comment: @Ayxan nope it won't. Well at least not the iteration part.

Comment: @M.Spiller no need to go that far xD. OP mentioned he'll be using a container. I see no benefit whatsoever to move to `void*`

Comment: @theWiseBro exactly. OP said that it should work with _one specific type_. Therefore there is no benefit to generalize it further.

Comment: @theWiseBro I understand what you meant. I'm not sure about OP's original intent, he just said want one specific type; you might need to explain it to OP. :)

Comment: I am trying to pass a `std::set<std::string>` undefined reference to `void foo<std::set>(std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&)'`

Comment: @chatzich Could you make a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for it? I tried it with `std::set` [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VSIzX5gi2Hb2ZNAW) and seems working fine.

Comment: @theWiseBro you can pass an array with reference and the iteration part will work.

Comment: too complex. a simple template would serve the purpose. See @Caleth 's reply.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on if you want to overload `foo` for other cases or not

```
// Doesn't participate in overload resolution when not applicable
template<typename Container, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename Container::value_type, std::string>>>
void foo(const Container &cont) {
   for(std::string val: cont) {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
   }
}

// simpler
template<typename Container>
void foo(const Container &cont) {
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Container::value_type, std::string>, "Container must contain std::string")
   for(std::string val: cont) {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
   }
}
```

You might use a different test to [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), such as [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) to allow

```
std::vector<char *> c_strings;
foo(c_strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using iterators instead. An intermediate result may look like

```
template<typename Iter>
void foo(Iter begin, Iter end) {
  using T = decltype(*begin);
  std::for_each(begin, end, [] (cons T & t) {
    std::out << t << '\n';
  }
}
```

Now using a callable template:

```
template<typename Iter, typename Callable>
void foo(Iter begin, Iter end, Callable & c) {
  std::for_each(begin, end, c);
}
```

We just learned to use what the STL already offers.

Answer (score -1):

Adding on to @songyuanyao's answer, I think we can generalize it further to:

```
template<template<typename...> typename C, typename ... D>
void foo(const C<D...> &cont)
{
   for(const auto& val: cont) {
      std::cout << val << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict the element type to std::string, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Sasha It's true that this is not fixed to std::string but it's more generalized. The OP wants to use a specific type. Say today he's using std::string and tomorrow he wants to use a MyCustomString instead. Wouldn't this prove easier to maintain since he only has to edit the code at a single place?

Comment: But this doesn't show how to restrict it to *either* std::string or MyCustomString elements - and the querent specifically wanted to take "a container *with a specific type*". As is, it'll accept any type that happens to be a template, and at that point why not just template it on a single <typename C> instead? That's much simpler and slightly more generalised - e.g. yours will take an std::string (aka std::basic_string<char>) as the container but not a custom struct MyCustomString, so it's not fully generic.

Comment: And if the function expects the elements to be std::string, allowing users to pass an std::tuple<int, double, std::nullptr_t> makes it *harder* to use and maintain.

Comment: @Sasha hmm. I see your point. That's true. Thanks for the heads up!